# pass by value not supported XDP

Tags: c, xdp-bpf, xdp-ebpf

I am creating a function to loop through some loops and try to match a set. It is supposed to work fine, but unfortunately, it is not. I get a "pass by value not supported" error. How can I fix this?

```
    int matchSet(Program p, int match[], int action)
    {
    int matchState = 0;
    int match[4] = {3,4,5,6}; //set as example
    int p.set[10] = {2,1,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12}; //set as example (normal p.set)

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (matchState != 2)
            {
                if (p.set[i] == match[0] && p.set[i + 1] == match[1])
                {
                    matchState = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
                    {
                        bpf_printk("test");
                        if (matchState == 0)
                        {
                            bpf_printk("test3");
                            if (p.set[i] != match[j])
                            {
                                bpf_printk("test4");
                                matchState = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (matchState == 0)
                    {
                        bpf_printk("test6");
                        matchState = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    if(matchState == 2) {
        return action;
    }
}
```

I call the function by:

```
Program p;
.....
int set[10] = {2,1,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12};
p.set = set;
int match[4] = {3,4,5,6};
matchSet(p, match, 1);
```

Error:

```
error: pass by value not supported 0x1aca7c8: i64 = GlobalAddress<i32 (%struct.Program*, i8*, i32)* @matchSet> 0
```

Comment: Hi Fabian, have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function to take a pointer to a Program like so:

```c
int matchSet(Program *p, int match[], int action){
...
```

And then also change your callsite:

```c
Program p;
matchSet(&p, match, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this is not working for me. When I do this (and change p.set to p->set (as it is now a pointer)), the values will not work and match anymore It reaches only till "test4" but it needs to match till "test6". I also needed to add extra if statements to check if all attributes of the Program struct exist. Otherwise, I did get the error "R2 invalid mem access 'mem_or_null'". Do you have any other advise?